# sql server full text index delay

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing

there is a delay in updating the full text index in sql server.

so it raises some problems.

I need to know the last item processed by full text index so i could find it in a search.

how can i get the last item primary key id processed by full text index in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's a guarantee anywhere that the index will be built/populated in any specific order (e.g. PK or clustered index).

If you need to know that a specific row has been added to the index, the only thing I can think to do (other than waiting for all indexing activity to cease) is to store unique values in another column, and then keep querying the index until the unique value for your row appears.

Answer (score -1):

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: ...whereas your answer has nothing to do with full text indexing